# How to carry out to 3 decimals rather than ints in the list?

Tags: python, python-2.x

So a list from 0 to 100 is created and I apply the formula in line two to make list B. The issue is that it's rounded to an int and I have been trying how to get it out to 3 decimals.

```
A = range(0,101)
B = [(x-10)/3 for x in A]
```

Ex:
If A = 11
(11-10)/3 = 0.333 instead of (11-10)/3 = 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Divide by 3. instead by 3

Comment: As @AndiKleve pointed out, and if you want to have three decimals then use `round(x, 3)`, where `x` is the number you want to round.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function round(B, 3)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
from __future__ import division
A = range(0,101)
B = [(x-10)/3 for x in A]
```